# Singleton Pattern: getInstance() vs Passing the singleton object?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

What is the right / most popular way to utilize the Singleton Pattern.

1. Limit the no. of calls to getInstance(), preferably call it only once, and pass the object around to other classes during their instantiation?

```java
class SingletonClass {
// Implementataion
}

class MainClass {
    private SingletonClass singletonClassObject;

    public MainClass() {
        singletonClassObject = SingletonClass.getInstance();
        new SomeClass(singletonClassObject).doSomething();
        new SomeOtherClass(singletonClassObject).doSomethingElse();
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    private SingletonClass singletonClassObject;

    public SomeClass(SingletonClass singletonClassObject) {
        this.singletonClassObject = singletonClassObject;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(singletonClassObject.getStuff());
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    private SingletonClass singletonClassObject;

    public SomeOtherClass(SingletonClass singletonClassObject) {
        this.singletonClassObject = singletonClassObject;
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println(singletonClassObject.getStuff());
    }
}
```

2. Don't pass the singleton object around. Rather call get the object reference in each class and save the reference as an instance variable and use it wherever required.

```java
class SingletonClass {
// Implementataion
}

class MainClass {
    public MainClass() {
        new SomeClass().doSomething();
        new SomeOtherClass().doSomethingElse();
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    private SingletonClass singletonClassObject;

    public SomeClass() {
        singletonClassObject = SingletonClass.getInstance();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(singletonClassObject.getStuff());
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    private SingletonClass singletonClassObject;

    public SomeOtherClass() {
        singletonClassObject = SingletonClass.getInstance();
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println(singletonClassObject.getStuff());
    }
}
```

3. Don't even save the reference as an instance variable, rather use SingletonClass.getInstance() everywhere you need the object.

```java
class SingletonClass {
// Implementataion
}

class MainClass {
    public MainClass() {
        new SomeClass().doSomething();
        new SomeOtherClass().doSomethingElse();
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass() {
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(SingletonClass.getInstance().getStuff());
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    public SomeOtherClass() {
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println(SingletonClass.getInstance().getStuff());
    }
}
```

How do these approaches compare with each other w.r.t. better design, testability etc? Which is better and why?

Comment: If you're going to pass the object to your methods, why do you need a singleton?

Comment: Could be for a variety of reasons. e.g. each instance of this class holds up a lot of resources and your use case can do with only one object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume for a moment that `SingletonClass` is not a singleton and we do not get an instance by calling `static` method we face another problem, how to link these classes together. This problem is solved by `Dependency Injection` and this concept is well described here:

- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)
- [Unit Testing 101: Inversion Of Control](https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-101-inversion)

After reading above it should be easy to choose option `.1` where all classes get in constructor references to required dependencies. You can even create an `interface` for a behaviour you need and implement it in `SingletonClass`. Now you see, that a fact that class implements [Singleton](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) pattern does not make it special and we should inject them like other classes. All benefits from using `DI` you can apply to your class.

Just compare it with `.3` and you need to write a test where you need mock something. It would be more unpleasant task then in case of `.1`.

Comment: Exactly. This is how all the well known *IOC* containers are designed. *Singleton* is defined by configuration rather than *hardcoding* this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way: you're questioning the compiler's ability to recognize that a static final reference can be compiled as an inline reference.

I would guess the compiler converts the getInstance() to an inline reference.  I would be less confident that the compiler would recognize that you're intentionally creating extra work for yourself when you pass a reference by value, and that it would create an extra reference on the stack when you passed it around.

My guess is that getInstance() would be more efficient.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I'm convinced the answer is correct.  The Java compiler is brilliant at figuring out inline references, but ... and here's the kicker ... references as method parameters in Java are *always* passed by value which means that it should create a copy on the stack.  The compiler may be so brilliant that it figures out what you're trying to do and breaks its own rules, but the rules say by value which means an extra stack allocation.

Comment: Well, I'm not really comparing the performances per se. I'm more interested from a design point of view, as in, which approach is more maintainable, readable, testable and such. And which approach is generally used in the industry.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be more maintainable than being able to look at any single use of an object and immediately know what it is and how it's designed.  :D

Comment: The one exception I can imagine is when the Singleton class is behind a verbose facade, like the standard Spring beans.  I would imagine typing in the Spring getters every time you use a bean would be a prohibitive amount of typing (I'm aware that you can rewire Spring to use non-singleton implementations, but generally speaking nobody does)..